# How to get input and output parameter to the all stored procedures in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to retrive through a stored procedure all the stored procedures in my database.

I have create a new stored procedure with this query:

```
select SPECIFIC_NAME 
from information_schema.routines 
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Now I want to know also, the input and output parameter that these stored procedures have, but I don't find how can I find these informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to get all the parameters in stored procedures

```
SELECT 
    SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) AS [Schema], 
    SO.name AS [Object Name],
    SO.Type_Desc AS [Object Type (UDF/SP)],
    P.parameter_id AS [Parameter ID],
    P.name AS [Parameter Name],
    TYPE_NAME(P.user_type_id) AS [Parameter Datatype],
    P.max_length AS [ParameterMaxBytes],
    P.is_output AS [IsOutPutParameter]
FROM 
    sys.objects AS SO
INNER JOIN 
    sys.parameters AS P ON SO.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
WHERE 
    SO.OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID 
                     FROM sys.objects
                     WHERE TYPE IN ('P', 'FN'))
ORDER BY 
    [Schema], SO.name, P.parameter_id
```